# How to have a class modify the pointer to itself so I can return to it easily

Tags: c++

Can you help me with the nomenclature I'm missing to achieving the following scenario?

In my program, I set the following classes:

- "Patient" has an integer for his "id", and a string for "sickness".
- "Doctor" has an integer for his "id", and a vector of integers "listOfPatients".

Later I push the iD of a patient into the doctor's vector .

How can I use the content of the vector to access the sickness of the related patient by matching IDs?

I guess this is probably possible while setting up the Patient class but I do not know the nomenclature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Patient{

// MAGIC PROBABLY HAPPENS SOMEWHERE HERE TO SET THE ADDRESS OF THE PATIENT EQUAL TO ITS idPatient

    public :
        int idPatient;
        string sickness;
        

        Patient(int idPatient, string sickness) {
        this->idPatient = idPatient;
        this->sickness = sickness;
        }
};

class Docteur {
    public :
        int idDocteur;
        vector <int> listePatients;

        Docteur(int idDocteur)  {
        this->idDocteur = idDocteur;
        }

        void addPatient(int idPatient) {
            listePatients.push_back(idPatient);
            cout << "\n Patient # " << idPatient << " has been added for doctor # " << idDocteur << "\n " ;
        }
};

int main()
{
Docteur doc1(9999);
Patient pat1(123, "vertigo");
doc1.addPatient(123);

// HERE I NEED TO ACCESS A PATIENT'S SICKNESS ACCORDING TO HIS ID... 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a real application you'd probably want to set this up using a database.

Comment: Why not `std::vector<Patient>` instead of storing ints?

Comment: @RetiredNinja you'd want a single patient to be able to have more than one doctor, wouldn't you?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You might want a `std::map<int, Patient>`, but the Patient class should not care about its own location and cannot modify its own address.

Comment: @MarkRansom In a perfect world, yes, but for a simple exercise maybe not. A container of all patients and functionality to look them up works too. *shrug*

Comment: *"help me with the nomenclature I'm missing"* --  ??? The nomenclature is just the name for something. Knowing the name will not help you implement the thing. For example, knowing that "queue" is the name of a certain data structure does not help you implement a queue. Why make the nomenclature the top priority in your question?

Comment: *"How can I use the content of the vector to access the sickness of the related patient by matching IDs?"* -- well, your example has only one patient, so looking up that patient is rather trivial. Perhaps you should give an example with more than one patient? Do you plan to store them in a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have designed your program in such a way that you cannot easily find a patient with a specific ID.

By using the lines

```
Docteur doc1(9999);
Patient pat1(123, "vertigo");
```

you have specified that every doctor and every patient will have its own unique identifier (name of variable or object). This is not a very flexible way of arranging your data.

It would make more sense to create a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for each class, like this:

```
std::vector<Docteur> doctors;
std::vector<Patient> patients;
```

After adding doctors and patients to both vectors using [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), you can access the first doctor with ID `0` with this expression: `doctors[0]`, or the third patient with ID `2` with the expression `patients[2]`. This assumes that the ID of the object is implied by the position in the vector. In that case, there is no need anymore for these objects to store their own ID as part of the object, so these member variables can be removed (unless you want member functions to print the ID for diagnostic purposes). Only the IDs stored in the `listePatients` member variable will still have to be stored.

---

> How can I use the content of the vector to access the sickness of the related patient by matching IDs?

If you rearrange your program as described above, if you want to access the sickness of the fourth patient of the second doctor, you can access it using the following expression:

`patients[doctors[1].listePatients[3]].sickness`

In code belonging to a member function of an object of `class Docteur`, you can access the sickness of the fourth patient of that doctor using the following expression:

`patients[this->listePatients[3]].sickness`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try that and might hit you back later tonight or tomorrow if I hit a snag.

Comment: @Vince if for some reason you need more flexibility in you IDs, you can use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: @MarkRansom thank you Mark. I'm unfamiliar with those functions at this moment so I will take a moment to educate myself on them.

Answer (score -1):

You have no control over the address. They are decided rather randomly during runtime. Allocating on the stack results in objects having address somewhere after it's beginning. While allocating on the heap usually returns a rather random address.

Furthermore, objects can be moved having their intrinsics stolen to a different location with a different address.

You have [XY type of problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You ought to search for a different type of solution for the problem at hand.

Comment: Wow okay, I wasn't aware it would be this complicated. I'll think about another solution. The contraints I have is that a doctor won't ever have more than five patients so I guess I could code them individually as members of Doctor. I was hoping to do something prettier. Thank you!